# EnvironmentHubMember object is not available in salesforce sandbox,But this sandbox has 'Environment hub org id ',How can i enable it?

Tags: soql, object, standard

EnvironmentHubMember object is not available in salesforce sandbox,But this sandbox has 'Environment hub org id' ,How can i enable it?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps mentioned in this documentation: [Get Started with the Environment Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_get_started.htm)?

Comment: I am not getting 'Manage Environment Hub' option in 'Administrativer permissions' section.